# Save entity object with foreign key using CrudRepository

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have two entity classes with @ManyToOne relationship as below.

```
@Entity
public class Student {

  @Id
  private Integer studentId;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String studentName;

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = School.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "schoolId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private School school;

  //Getters and Setters methods
```

.

```
@Entity
public class School {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer schoolId;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String schoolName;

  //Getters and Setters methods
```

When I try to save the student object using CrudRepository default method `studentRepository.save(student)` with JSON payload, it gives me an error `java.sql.SQLException: Field 'school_id' doesn't have a default value`.  When I run in the debug mode I can see that the School object is being set correctly.

My JSON payload is as follows:

```
[
    {
      "studentId": "2015020",
      "studentName": "ABC",
      "school": {
        "schoolId": 1
      }
    }
]
```

I am new to Spring Data JPA, so this might be a very basic mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the column name `collegeId` to `schoolId` in table `school`, and then modify this line:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = School.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "schoolId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private School school;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo and I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

In the entity `Student` the property `school` is an object. To insert new student you must use a reference to `school` object. So your payload must be like this:

```
{
    "studentId": 2015020,
    "studentName": "ABC",
    "school": "http://localhost:8080/api/schools/1"
}
```

Also you can simplify the definition of the property `school`:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private School school;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the name of database column match with entity mapping:
If identity column of school table in DB is "school_id", mention it in your mapping:

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "school_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer schoolId;
```